# When user submit form then how to send whatsapp message automatically

Tags: whatsapp

I have created one web form and my input filed are (name, contact no, message) when user submit form then I have to send PDF but without opening WhatsApp in their side so how can I send that??

As we know when we book our movie ticket online then we receive PDF of our ticket I have to do the same how can I do that?

can someone guide me?